# Giving a parameter from VBA to Powershell

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-access, powershell-4.0

From VBA code in Access 2013 I am trying to run an PowerShell script which accepts 1 parameter. This parameter is supplied (and set) from within Access (VBA).

Though I noticed the script wasnt enttirely excuted the right way. It runs a application which merges some PDF files toghter. The supplied parameter let the application know which folder, that contains the PDF files, it should merge.

This parameter wasnt taken into account for though.

My VBA script it as follows:

```
Err = Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File G:\OPSPDF\MergeFiles.ps1 -path """ & MergedFolder & """ ", 1)
```

The MergedFolder parameter is a string path to the folder which contains the PDF files to merge `("O:\documents\somefiles")`

My powershell script is as follows:

```
param([String] $inputfolder)

$PDFtk = "D:\Test\pdftk.exe"
 $outputfile = "MergedFile.pdf"

dir $inputfolder -r -include *.pdf -exclude $outputfile | group DirectoryName |  
% {& $PDFtk $_.group CAT OUTPUT "$($_.Name)\$outputfile"}

cmd /c pause | out-null
```

The `PDFtk` is the location where the `exe` is in which it should launch. The pause is build in to see what goes wrong.

Because it didnt work correctly I try'd to echo my given parameter from VBA in the powershell script like so:

```
param([String] $inputfolder)

echo $inputfolder

$PDFtk = "D:\Test\pdftk.exe"

 $outputfile = "MergedFile.pdf"

dir $inputfolder -r -include *.pdf -exclude $outputfile | group DirectoryName |  
% {& $PDFtk $_.group CAT OUTPUT "$($_.Name)\$outputfile"}

cmd /c pause | out-null
```

Tho nothing was echo'd so that made me believe that perhaps there was going something wrong with the variable in VBA that is given as parameter (this contains some special characters like `\`) so I replaced the `MergedFolder` variable for a hard coded string like this:

```
Err = Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File G:\OPSPDF\MergeFiles.ps1 -path "" TestString "" ", 1)
```

But still it doesn't echo anything... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As a matter of interest if you paste the exact same command into a RUN dialogue do you get the same result or does it work?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have `inputputfolder` parameter in your script (`$inputfolder`), but you're passing `-path` parameter in your VBA code.
2. Try removing quotes around your test string:

   ```
   Err = Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File G:\OPSPDF\MergeFiles.ps1 -inputfolder TestString", 1)
   ```

Comment: Nope sadly still doesn't echo with the modifications you suggested. Also added a `echo "test"` behind the `echo #inputfolder` to see if it does anything at all but the `echo "test"` in the ps script does work.

Comment: Whenever you use paths you still need quotes so you can account for spaces, which will just ruin everything. Use single quotes or escape characters: `Err = Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'G:\OPSPDF\MergeFiles.ps1' -inputfolder 'TestString'", 1)`